# how can i read mp4 fille in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, encoding

i am trying to create a video downloader and sender
but the problem is when i try to read the .mp4 in string the letters changes i think its a problem with the encoding

example to the problem

i use this code to download a video

```vb
            My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(url, path & ".mp4")
```

now if you tried to do this

```vb
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("1c.mp4", IO.File.ReadAllText(path & ".mp4"), False)
```

1c.mp4 will not work

Comment: You've already downloaded the file. Have you tried playing that rather than re-saving it as text? The latter won't work.

Comment: Don't use the xxxText() methods, use something like [ReadAllBytes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.readallbytes?view=net-5.0) and [WriteAllBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.writeallbytes?view=net-5.0) that work with BYTE ARRAYS.   Or use FileStreams, or maybe just [CopyFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.copyfile?view=net-5.0)?